# Using for loop data to for 10 rows at a time

Tags: php

I could not find an answer to this question or I completely missed the answer, what I am doing is looping from a database, just a number value, this variable **$competition['competition_number_of_tickets']** could be for example 200.

```
                  <?php
                  $counter = 0;
                  for ($i = 1; $competition['competition_number_of_tickets'] >= $i; $i++) {
                    if ($i % 10 === 0) {
                        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary\">{$i}</button>";       
                    } else {
                        echo "<hr />"; 
                    }
                  }               
                  ?>
```

The way my code is now, each button lists 1 after each other, what I'm trying to do is have 10 buttons on each row to make it look nicer, I know that my code is not working as expected could anyone explain what I'm doing wrong? I'm not great with maths.

Comment: Are you trying to alternate `<button>` / `<hr/>` on each loop iteration? Try `if ($i % 2 === 0)` to alternate odd/even. You could also just combine the cases in all likelihood.

Comment: Really what I was trying to do is 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 (then hr rule) 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 (then hr rule) etc all the way down :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop should compare `$i` to the total, as in

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $competition['competition_number_of_tickets']; $i++)
```

Then, your modulus will fire every time the counter gets to a multiple of 10, but the way you have it now (which is reversed from how you want it) it will show a button only when the counter gets to a multiple of 10.  Even if you had that right, it would still ignore ignore the 10th button. Your if statement should look more like

```
echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary\">{$i}</button>";       
if ($i % 10 === 0) echo "<hr />";
```

Comment: Thank you very much that is perfect and I know what I did wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

##### Alternative answer

You can use [`array_chunk`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) and [`range`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range) :

```
$data = array_chunk(range(1, $competition['competition_number_of_tickets']), 10, true);

foreach ($data as $items) {
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary\">" . $item . "</button>";
    }

    echo '<hr>';
}
```

Output :

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">3</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">5</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">6</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">7</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">8</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">9</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">10</button>
<hr />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">11</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">12</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">13</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">14</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">15</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">16</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">17</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">18</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">19</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">20</button>
<hr />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">21</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">22</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">23</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">24</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">25</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">26</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">27</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">28</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">29</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">30</button>
<hr />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">31</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">32</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">33</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">34</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">35</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">36</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">37</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">38</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">39</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">40</button>
<hr />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">41</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">42</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">43</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">44</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">45</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">46</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">47</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">48</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">49</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">50</button>
<hr />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">51</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">52</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">53</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">54</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">55</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">56</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">57</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">58</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">59</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">60</button>
<hr />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">61</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">62</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">63</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">64</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">65</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">66</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">67</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">68</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">69</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">70</button>
<hr />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">71</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">72</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">73</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">74</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">75</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">76</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">77</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">78</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">79</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">80</button>
<hr />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">81</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">82</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">83</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">84</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">85</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">86</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">87</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">88</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">89</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">90</button>
<hr />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">91</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">92</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">93</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">94</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">95</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">96</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">97</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">98</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">99</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">100</button>
<hr />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">101</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">102</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">103</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">104</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">105</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">106</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">107</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">108</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">109</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">110</button>
<hr />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">111</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">112</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">113</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">114</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">115</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">116</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">117</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">118</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">119</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">120</button>
<hr />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">121</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">122</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">123</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">124</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">125</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">126</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">127</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">128</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">129</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">130</button>
<hr />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">131</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">132</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">133</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">134</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">135</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">136</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">137</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">138</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">139</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">140</button>
<hr />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">141</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">142</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">143</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">144</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">145</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">146</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">147</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">148</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">149</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">150</button>
<hr />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">151</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">152</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">153</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">154</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">155</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">156</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">157</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">158</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">159</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">160</button>
<hr />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">161</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">162</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">163</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">164</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">165</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">166</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">167</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">168</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">169</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">170</button>
<hr />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">171</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">172</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">173</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">174</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">175</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">176</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">177</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">178</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">179</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">180</button>
<hr />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">181</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">182</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">183</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">184</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">185</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">186</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">187</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">188</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">189</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">190</button>
<hr />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">191</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">192</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">193</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">194</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">195</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">196</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">197</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">198</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">199</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">200</button>
<hr />
```